# Where are Processing libraries installed when added from the Sketch menu?

Tags: processing

When I add a library in Processing (Sketch > Import Library > Add Library), where is it installed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They're installed in your **sketchbook location**.

You can view and change your sketchbook location by going to File > Preferences. The sketchbook location setting is the first option in that dialog:

[image: Processing sketchbook location dialog]

This sketchbook location is also where your settings are stored, as well as the default place where sketches are saved.

You could have probably figured this out by googling "processing library directory" or by just installing a library and then searching for a directory with that name.

Comment: They end up in `~\documents\libraries` whereas I was looking in `~\documents\processing\libraries` which also exists. I was able to find it with the local search. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 3):

It's in the `libraries` folder of your Processing sketch folder. On my Mac, it's ~/Documents/Processing 3.0/libraries/

Comment: True for Mac. I found it there as well. I also need to find it in Windows. It's not in the same location in that case.